# "ЖД-станция" — можно ли так написать?

Tags: орфография, сложные-слова

**"ЖД-станция"** — можно ли так написать? Как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: Ж/д, ж.д - железная дорога и ж.-д. железнодорожная станция.

Обратите внимание: дефис после сокращения не нужен.

> См.: Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.